# How to Sum the Group value and subtract of received value?

Tags: crystal-reports

I am generating the crystal report in which grouping by Type ,their are two types income and deduction.Each group have it sum(total).I have applied sum({table.field_to_summarize},{table.field_you_are_grouping_on}).Net amount should be soon at report Footer, sum of income - sum of deduction gives net Amount,
but it give me 0 as value

```
Group      
       Income          
       50
       40         
       10
       100 <- sum of the Income 

       Deduction
       40         
       10
       50 <- sum of the Deduction 

net    50 <- sum of the Income  - sum of the Deduction
```

Comment: Have you created a formula for the net amount? Could you share the formula?

Comment: i have created Formula field sum({table.field_to_summarize},{table.field_you_are_grouping_on}) formula For A (Income group)and sum({table.field_to_summarize},{table.field_you_are_grouping_on}) For B (Deduction group).Net formula field is A-B

Comment: Have you created any variables and then subtracted from those or just subtractracted as it is? becuase from your explanation I see no issue with the logic and you should get the result.

Answer (score 0):

Try using running total.

Create two Running total formulas Each to summarize based on type(Income and Deduction). While creating running total in the evaluate condition  use "Formula" like

```
IF Type = "Income" Then True
```

and similarly for deduction. Place these formulas on the group footer.

Now for your Net Amount formula simply do Runningtotal1 - Runningtotal2 and place it in the report footer.

This should give you the result.

Hope this helps!